# Adding a reference to a library project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have a problem when I want to add a reference to google-play-services_lib of my Android project with Eclipse. 
I followed the steps described here on developer.android.com and it seems to work when i do the add because i have this icon : [image: http://cyberterry.fr/pb_library2.png]

But after, when i click on apply/ok and i close this window, if i re-opens the same window i have this icon :

[image]

I don't understand..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try adding it in JAVA BUILD PATH , under Projects Tab as well

Comment: Enable Build Automatically option from project menu and try. make sure that you will not move library project on another path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside "android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs" you have a .jar called "google-play-services.jar" copy this .jar into a folder called "libs" in the root of your project. Forgot about adding in this way you are adding. It must work.