# unable to resolve static method: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable

Tags: android, google-play-services

ok...this is driving me nuts.

I've added and re-added the Google Play Services Lib multiple times (with and without copying to workspace) but when I try adding it as a reference to my project, it always shows as a red X next to it when I go back to the project properties as in this guy's screen captures:
  [Adding a reference to a library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810583/adding-a-reference-to-a-library-project)

No errors print to the console.  Anyone know why this would show up as a red X or how to debug this?  I've added Android Bar Sherlock the same way w/o issues.  It's just the Google Play Services library that's driving me up the wall :-P

I also tried creating a new project and following this quickstart and have the same issue.  It's almost like my Eclipse is broken in some way but it's a fresh install :-P
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

I can work around the compile time errors by adding the library in the project properties java build path, but this should not be the way to fix it.  And if I try running the app on my SGS3 this way, it crashes w/ the error in the title.  I can add the play library jar to my libraries, but then it crashes with an error about looking having problems looking up r$styled so that doesn't work either :-P

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to import from YOUR_PATH\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib?

Comment: Yep.  Have done it over 10 times now.  Looked at probably 10 different stackoverflow answers.

What's really weird is that on a laptop I brought with me to Google I/O this year, I installed a few of their labs which uses play services and in the samples, it shows up w/ a green check in the ProjectSettings|Android|Library list.  On that same laptop, I tried following the quickstart sample and got a red X.  This just baffles me.  I've compared settings between the good/bad projects w/o luck too :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally.  Got bit by this:

[unable to resolve static method: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606319/unable-to-resolve-static-method-lcom-google-android-gms-common-googleplayservic)
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27199

Everything runs properly now.
Damned annoying bug.  I remember being bit by it years ago and it's still not fixed :-P

Comment: link in the answer is to this question you are asking. Nice recursive pattern you have managed to attain.